# Is broadcast DATA_SMS_RECEIVED on the Whitelist for implicit broadcast receivers?

Tags: android, android-intent

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

states that SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION is on the whitelist, but DATA_SMS_RECEIVED is not mentioned.

I currently am updating my app to the current versions and now receiving data sms stopped to work. I suspect, that DATA_SMS_RECEIVED is now blocked from the implicit broadcasts.

Anybody with deeper insights?

Comment: I just ran a quick test on my 8.0 device, and data SMS still works for me. What have you tested on? Emulators? Devices?

Comment: I tested on a real device (Nexus 5X) with Android 8.1
But as I am in the middle of migrating to AndroidX it might be possible that problems also from that side are introduced. Wanted to make sure that it makes sense to dig deeper there.

Comment: You might test on some emulators. I'll do that, too, when I get a chance, later on.

Comment: I would be interested how to test data_sms on an emulator. Currently I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can run two emulators simultaneously, and send between them. The number to use is the port number – e.g., 5554 – which should be part of the name in the title bar, IIRC. It's been a while since I've done it myself.

Comment: But the upcoming restrictions to SMS in the Play-Store might force me to ditch this option. Or do you know of a method to send data-sms in a then compliant way?

Comment: ... ok. The last time I researched on that, that method was told to be unreliable. So I didn't try myself ... But if you say you succeeded, it might be worth to try myself. ;-)

Comment: AFAIK, all direct usage of `SmsManager` is prohibited, unless it's a main function of your app. The only general exemption I've heard of is for task scheduler-type apps. Of course, you could always offer your app through other channels, too. As far as the emulator thing, yeah, I think it used to be rather flaky, but with recent versions, I've never had a problem.

Comment: Well, looks like possibly bad news, as far as emulator tests for data SMS. I couldn't get that to work on any version, and after a little research, it seems the emulators have never supported data SMS. The info I found was pretty dated, so I'm gonna do a few more tests, just to make sure, but it looks like we might be out of luck. I'll let ya know.

Comment: I also tested yesterday. I was able to send Text-SMS from one emulator to the other (nice! ;-) I should have tried that earlier!), but also did not succeed in sending Data-SMS. :-/

But the crucial point will be if I get the permission from Google to continue to use this permission. Somehow I doubt that ...

Comment: Yeah, what a pain, right? Unfortunately, I don't have any 8.1 devices, so I'm not sure that I can be of any more help to ya. I will let you know if I find out anything new, but I'm not very hopeful.

Comment: Hey, you might be interested in this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62052486. I found it while confirming and researching another emulator SMS bug. Guess what? Multipart text messages choke on the emulators, too. They end up as garbage on the receiving end. Nifty, eh?

Comment: Thank you for your input! From the last comment there it seems that this fix hasn't made it to the final release?

Anyway: As this is a nice-to-have feature for my app, i wait for the answer from Google for permission to use those permissions before I put more work into this. If they deny, that work would be for the trash-bin.